# Create exe to monitor service in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-services, exe

I've created a windows service project, but I need to create another project to monitor this service.

I was told to create an exe application, but I don't know which type of project to create in VS 2010 that will generate a exe file that can monitor the windows service I've created.

Thanks!

Comment: If the monitor should be hidden, how does it need to monitor the service? If hidden, maybe you just need to add logging to the service and then check out the logs when you need to inspect its activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what is meant by "monitor". WinForms application will work.

Comment: @AndreMiranda You can just omit creation of the GUI window, or make it hidden. But still this would be a GUI application -- console application would create a console window by default, and it's harder to write and manage.